# How to display sequence of dates in rows to columns

Tags: mysql, rows

Table periods with primary field idPeriod and a few hundred records.
Table date_classes with idPeriod and dateClass
There are also names to display. Each name has the same period and the 5 dates.

Each period has 5 dates.

```
+-----------+------------+
| idPeriode | dateClass  |
+-----------+------------+
|    302367 | 2020-02-18 |
|    302367 | 2020-02-25 |
|    302367 | 2020-03-03 |
|    302367 | 2020-03-10 |
|    302367 | 2020-03-17 |
+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to show :

```
+----------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Name     | Period | Date1      | Date2      | Date3      | Date4      | Date5      |
+----------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Bousquet | 302367 | 2020-02-18 | 2020-02-25 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10 | 2020-03-17 |
| Grignon  | 302367 | 2020-02-18 | 2020-02-25 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10 | 2020-03-17 |
| Rajotte  | 302367 | 2020-02-18 | 2020-02-25 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10 | 2020-03-17 |
| Vandal   | 302367 | 2020-02-18 | 2020-02-25 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10 | 2020-03-17 |
| Tessier  | 302367 | 2020-02-18 | 2020-02-25 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10 | 2020-03-17 |
| Beauvais | 302367 | 2020-02-18 | 2020-02-25 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10 | 2020-03-17 |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Always in 1 week intervals?

Comment: idPeriodd cannot be a primary key as isn't not unique. Which MySQL version? Why repreat the same row for a bunch of names? that can be done in the application. Where do the set of names come from? Are they equaly appiled to each idPeriode?

Comment: What is tying the Name field into the idPeriode or dateClass fields?

Comment: 1) Most of the time it is 1 week interval; but occasionally a class will be postponed and a date will be added at the end of the sequence (an extra week) - the date of the week changed will not appear anymore - it will stay 5

Comment: 2) in the second table (date_Classes) the key is idPeriod + dateClass

Comment: 3) There are two more tables involved : client, where the client name comes from; clientclass which contains the class requested by the client - each request has its own key field - when a class is created with enough people, a period is created - each client of the group is given the idPeriod which is recorded in the table clientclass in a field called assignedPeriod - then 5 dates are added to the tales date_classes

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear why you want to do like that but it's achievable with a few functions implemented in the query. Refer following query for example:

```
SELECT NAME, idperiode,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(dateclass,',',1) AS date_1,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dateclass,',',2),',',-1) AS date_2,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dateclass,',',3),',',-1) AS date_3,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dateclass,',',4),',',-1) AS date_4,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(dateclass,',',-1) AS date_5
FROM       
(SELECT NAME,
       idperiode,
       GROUP_CONCAT(dateclass ORDER BY dateclass) AS dateclass 
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY NAME, idperiode) A;
```

The first part is a sub-query using `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all the dates (assuming that all these are in one table only). Then use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to separate the groupconcated dates. [You can view the demo fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gMSws8EYtYRMCCkg4tLWF5/0)

IF there are two tables with no relation, then you can use `CROSS JOIN` on the tables. I've also [prepared the fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jvwzAHmiU3ZRhqGTK2BtNf/6) with just a slight modification in the sub-query whereas the outer query still function the same.

Comment: Thank you - this is very interesting - I will need to adapt it, but it is a very good start.